# KIVY + PYTHON Class import issue

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Any ideas on this error? The class exists not in the "main.py" but in the "dashboard.py" view and then I want to use in the dashboard.kv view file.  When I put this class in main.py it works fine, but I do not want to clutter my main with all the code. I have tried multiple ways of importing it, but still the same error...

First import try:[image]

Here is how I am importing custom widget into the dashboard.kv from dashbutton.kv[image]

Here is how I am importing dashboard.py to main.py:[image]

Comment: Is dashboard.py imported in your python code, before the kv is loaded?

Comment: in your python code the class definition Dashboard is above ButtDash so possibly reversing those can get rid of the error.  Also in your Kivy code you should show inheritance, instead of <ButtDash> try <ButtDash@BoxLayout>

Comment: thanks Mark and inclement, your suggestions worked! I was not aware that the main class needs to be last and that inheritance matters here